# How to remove part of a string Monogdb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to delete everything after the first \n in this string:

```
https://media.test.com/$main$\n \n https://media.xl?$desktop$\n \n https://media.com/$desktop/\n \n
```

Collection;
    { id:....
      class: "Apples"
      Url: " https://media.test.com/$main$\n \n https://media.xl?$desktop$\n \n 
    https://media.com/$desktop/\n \n"

So the desired output is, filter on class: "Apples" and turn url into:

```
https://media.test.com/$main$
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$indexOfBytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/) returns first occurence of given substring so you can use it along with [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) to find your first `\n` and get a substring:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            newString: { $substr: [ "$str", 0, { $indexOfBytes: [ "$str", "\n" ] } ] }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/skS7nakrbhR)

Comment: Error message from this: "errmsg" : "$substrBytes:  length must be a numeric type (is BSON type null)",

Comment: @Kingswoop you need to filter out those documents that doesn't contain string field like: https://mongoplayground.net/p/SE5k9GItWAC

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have so far given the above comment;

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
      $match: {
           class: "Apples"
      }
  },
  {
        $project: {
        newString: { $substr: [ "$str", 0, { $indexOfBytes: [ "$str", "\n" ] } ] }
        }
    }
])
```

getting the error;
Error message from this: "errmsg" : "$substrBytes: length must be a numeric type (is BSON type null)",